# Division of percentage dependent on number of columns

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

I'm styling up a bar chart. There are potentially unlimited bars and I need them each to have a proportional width to their parent container- currently I have something like:

```
.one-column  {
    width: (100% / 1);
}

.two-columns {
    width: (100% / 2);
}

.three-columns {
    width: (100% / 3);
}

etc
```

... which I would add to each bar.

Can anyone think of a clever way of getting around this and just having one rule that could handle unlimited columns - maybe something to do with data attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some tricky combinations of CSS3 selectors you could find out how many columns are in use and dependent on that style the width of the containers:

```
div:first-child:last-child {
width: 100%;
}
div:first-child:nth-last-child(2), div:last-child:nth-first-child(2) {
width: 50%;
}
div:first-child:nth-last-child(3), div:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ div {
width: 33.33%;
}
div:first-child:nth-last-child(4), div:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ div {
width: 25%;
}
```

As you can see, you will still need to add a rule for every possible number of divs, but you don't need to detect anymore how many divs are there and to set classes accordingly.

But there is also another possible solution in your case. You could use `display: table`, `display: table-cell` etc. on the divs and the parent element in an appropriate way. Then if you set the width of the parent to `100%` and the width of the containers to all the same value (e.g. `1%`), you will get exactly what you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't really see that being any more useful than what I currently have. Also can't seem to get the display: table method to work either, am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/c4BZT/

Comment: I tried your fiddle, but to me it works. What browser do you use?

Comment: Add `width: 1%` to the `li` in your fiddle, then it should also work in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) - it supports mathematical operations. Otherwise I'd recommend you use Javascript to handle the styling of your bars. Perhaps use a graph library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

Comment: Yep. scss also supports mathematical operations - but sass and less are pre-processors so do the maths before they could get the value of data-column (for example), so that wouldn't work. I'm looking for a css / scss only solution.

Comment: Apologies, didn't notice you were using scss. Still, I strongly suggest you use Javascript for this.